# bin size in pyramid_chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently trying to understand why the bin size in my pyramid chart in R (running in JupyterNotebook) is off.

I have a very simple table from where I use 3 variables: `gender`, `age group`, and `count`.

See table below:

[image]

And ran a `pyramid_chart`, however, the size of bars is off ,and I do not know how to fix it.

[image]

I tried to have a pyramid chart (also called as a `bidirectional chart` or a `side to side chart`), but I have issues with the `facet_share` that is giving me an error: `R[write to console]: Error in axes$y$left[[1]]$children$axis$grobs[[lab_idx]] :  attempt to select less than one element in get1index`.

The code I used looked as following:

[image]

**Data table**

```
val_gen_age<-data.frame(gender = c("Female", "Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male"), age group  = c("18-24", "25-34", "35-44","45-54","55-64","65+","18-24", "25-34", "35-44","45-54","55-64"),count = c("1270", "2280", "1257","855","180","450","1449","1170","89"))
```

Comment: What is off more precisely?

Comment: If you see the bar size on each age group level (e.g., 18-24 and then go up), you see that the yellow bars are bigger than the green bars.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: You need to have five categories for the males too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the bars differ because the groups are uneven. Group 55-64 is only present in `Female`. If you add a row with `add_row` filling in the counterpart of `age_group 55-64` for `Male` , then the bars will be as expected:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggcharts)

df1 <- df %>% 
   add_row(gender ="Male", age_group = "55-64", count = 0)
 
pyramid_chart(
  df1,
  age_group,
  count,
  gender,
  bar_colors =  c("darkgreen", "darkorange"),
  sort = "no",
  xlab = NULL,
  title = NULL
)
```

[image]

data:

```
structure(list(gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), age_group = c("18-24", 
"25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "18-24", "25-34", "35-44", 
"45-54"), count = c(1270L, 2280L, 1257L, 855L, 180L, 450L, 1449L, 
1170L, 89L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```